# Multiple one-to-many/one-to-one relationships to the same class in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Say I have a Person, Building, and Address class. A person can have many addresses and a building can have one address. In the DB, all three have their own separate table. The way the Address table is linked is by using a fk_id column and a type column. An address for a person is stored by storing the person_id as the fk_id and setting type to "person", whereas for a building you store the building_id as fk_id and set the type to "building". Is there any way to map these relationships or would I need to either convert the DB to use a linking table and do a many-to-many or just use HQL to retrieve that data?

Comment: How different your Building from Address?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The building is a completely different entity from the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, all that's needed is add a "where" condition on the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can map your entities like this.

```
<class name="Address">
    <id name="addressId" column="addressId">
       <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
</class>

<class name="Person">
    <id name="personId" column="personId">
       <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
   <set name="addresses" table="PersonAddress">
       <key column="personId"/>
       <many-to-many column="addressId"
         unique="true"
         class="Address"/>
   </set>
</class>

<class name="Building">
    <id name="id" column="buildingId">
       <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
   <many-to-one name="address" 
      column="addressId" 
      unique="true"
      not-null="true"/>
</class>
```

U just need an extra table PersonAddress.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. I know how to achieve what I need if I change the database structure, but I want to know if it can be done with the model I described (address table has fk_id field that could map to either address_id or person_id and a type field that can be set to either "person" or "building".

Answer (score 0):

You could map this as so:

```
@Entity
public class Address {
  @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
  private Person person;

  @OneToOne @JoinColumn(name="building_id")
  private Building building;
}

@Entity
public class Person {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="person", targetEntity=Address.class)
  private Set<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity
public class Building {
  @OneToOne(mappedBy="building")
  private Address address;
}
```

In this example, address could have either a Person or a Building (it should not have both).  Also, Address is considered the owner of the relationship, and Person or Building is the "inverse" side of that relationship.

That being said, to create the object graph, you could still use cascading saves (the "cascade" attribute on the annotations) so that you could create all the objects in memory, and simply save the Person or Building, and it should automagically save the Address objects along with it.

Comment: As I commented on the other response, I know how to achieve what I need if I change the database structure, but I want to know if it can be done without any changes. So for the building we'd be looking at something like this if using straight SQL:

Comment: `SELECT * FROM building b INNER JOIN address a ON b.building_id = a.fk_id AND a.type = 'building' WHERE b.building_id = 1`